# If $f_{xy}(a,b)\neq f_{yx}(a,b)$ then can we conclude that $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ are not continuous at $(a,b)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f$ be a real valued function defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2$

If $f_{xy}(a,b)\neq f_{yx}(a,b)$ then can we conclude that $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ are not continuous at $(a,b)$

If I remember correctly there is a theorem which states the above fact but I can not recall it. If anybody know the name of the result(theorem) please mention it.

Thanks.

Comment: It's a general statement that if $f$ is $C^2,$ i.e. its second derivatives all exist and are continuous, then $f_{xy}=f_{yx}$, so in your case, you only seem to be able to derive that either $f_{yx}$, $f_{xy}$, $f_{x^2}$ or $f_{y^2}$ is discontinuous.

Comment: Or... alternatively, one of them doesn't exist.

Comment: It's strengthening of Schwarz theorem by Peano, [here is the reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Sufficiency_of_twice-differentiability). It's actually stronger than this question, because we're only assuming existence of either $f_{xy}$ or $f_{yx}$, and not both.

Comment: Can be found at Rudin's Prinicples of Mathematical Analysis, page 235.

Comment: @Jakobian Thanks. If you wish you can put your both comments as answer, I will gladly accept it. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: It's all matter of searching, it was effortless. Posting it as an answer seems unfair. Thank you for the offer though.